# Get form inputs as Key/Values

Tags: javascript

I'm retrofitting an open source project with some additional input fields. What I need to be able to do is get pairs of input fields as key/value pairs and push them to an array.

Ignoring aesthetics, the general gist is:

```html
<input placeholder="Key1"> <input placeholder="Value1"> <!-- Pair 1 -->
<input placeholder="Key2"> <input placeholder="Value2"> <!-- Pair 2 -->
<input placeholder="Key3"> <input placeholder="Value3"> <!-- Pair 3 -->
```

How can I configure the input fields so they can be

1. Parsed as pairs
2. Future feature to allow dynamic addition of extra input fields (not too important yet)

```html
# Example
<button>Add New Key/Value</button>
```

I then expect to be able to parse it to an array of maps like so:

```js
let values = [
   {key: "Key1", value: "Value1"},
]
```

At the moment I have a single static pair with `id`'s set which I query

```js
var key1 = trim( $('#key1').val() );
var value1 = trim( $('#value1').val() );
```

But this isn't scalable or allows itself to be dynamic.

Note: I can't implement a framework like Vue or React, as this is an existing codebase.

Comment: at least the input elements must have a name. why use HTML if you don't want to respect the syntax rules?

Comment: Was asking for suggestions without trying to influence the responses. As mentioned at the bottom, I had used `id` and was statically querying them. Forgive me for asking a question on a programming Q&A forum.

Comment: this is nonsense, I will now have to apologize for indicating on this forum that your code does not respect W3C guidelines? If your code had followed them then you wouldn't have to do this tinkering since form elements work directly with a `(key, value)` system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the inputs, then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

In the reducer function, you can check whether the index is even or not. If it is, push to the array a new object with its `key` property set to the input's `placeholder` property. If not, set the array's last item's `value` property to the input's `placeholder` property.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#form1 input')

const values = [...inputs].reduce((a,b,i) => {
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    a.push({key:b.placeholder})
  }else{
    a[a.length - 1].value = b.placeholder;
  }
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(values)
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<input placeholder="Key1"> <input placeholder="Value1"> <!-- Pair 1 -->
<input placeholder="Key2"> <input placeholder="Value2"> <!-- Pair 2 -->
<input placeholder="Key3"> <input placeholder="Value3"> <!-- Pair 3 -->
</form>
```

Comment: you could explain what a,b and i are, that could be helpful if the user is new to reduce or some other looking for the same solution who are not familiar with reduce

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap each pair in  a containing element and map those containers returning an object for each container

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.input-container')

const arr = [...containers].map(el => {
     const inputs = el.querySelectorAll('input');
     return {key: inputs[0].placeholder , value: inputs[1].placeholder}

})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input placeholder="Key1"> <input placeholder="Value1">
  <!-- Pair 1 -->
</div>
<div class="input-container">
  <input placeholder="Key2"> <input placeholder="Value2">
  <!-- Pair 2 -->
</div>
<div class="input-container">
  <input placeholder="Key3"> <input placeholder="Value3">
  <!-- Pair 3 -->
</div>
```